# QProcess doesn't show any output when it runs rsync

Tags: c++, qt, rsync

I start rsync in QProcess. My process runs fine (in its own terminal) if I use `QProcess::startDetached()` but nothing happens if I start it with `QProcess:start()`. The problem seems to be that QProcess can't apparently read messages from rsync and write it to the output window.

I have connect this signal in constructor.

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    process = new QProcess(this);

    connect( process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(onReadyReadStandardOutput() ) );
}
```

Later on button clicked I call:

```
void MainWindow::onButton1Clicked()
{
    process->start("rsync -a root@10.0.0.1:/path/ /rsync_folder");

    //process->start("ping 10.0.0.01"); // this works for testing and I see output but not the above.
}
```

When rsync starts, it prints a message and ask for password..none of it is received by my QProcess but the `ping` message are received..what could be possibly wrong here?

The above grieving line also works directly on windows 7 command line but it just doesn't seem to show any progress in QProcess.

**Update**

Here is how I displaying the output.

```
void MainWindow::onReadyReadStandardOutput()
{
    qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, how do you know that messages from `ping` command are received in your application? They are not supposed to be visible unless you explicitly read them from `QProcess` via `readAllStandardOutput`  method for example and write it to log or elsewhere.

Comment: @olegandriyanove i have connected slot to it and i am using `qDebug()` to print out to output window

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#communicating-via-channels

Did you remember to link to and check the standard error channel?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError

That has fixed it for me in the past for some QProcesses I have started.

Another way I've done it, is to use `QProcess::startDetached();`

Hope that helps.

Comment: With startDetached() you don't get any output at all, do you?

Comment: `QProcess:startDetached()` works for me too but it runs on the command line byitself which I don't want. I do call `readAllStandardOutput()` but it sees no data.

Comment: I think part of the problem seem to be when I rsync (even on command line) sometime windows brings up security dialog to allow access to network (it brings this sometime but not all the time). This maybe holding the process but this dialog is never shown when ran through `QProcess`. Maybe there is a way I can disable this dialog and start `rsysnc`with parameters not to show messages/prompt etc?

Answer (score 0):

My research shows that rsync probably behaves like scp which accordingly this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773410/qprocess-output-not-showing?rq=1) doesn't generate output when it is redirected.